# Python-Selenium won't click button

Tags: python, selenium

The webpage i'm starting from is https://classschedule.tulane.edu/Search.aspx . The page source information for the button I need clicked is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSearchAll" value="All Courses" id="btnSearchAll" class="JQButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false" autocomplete="off" style="height: 22px;">
```

I have tried different methods to find this button and click on it such as;

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id("btnSearchAll")
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id ='btnSearchAll']")
element = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$MainContent$btnSearchAll")
```

I think it is finding the button because when I do...

```
print element
```

...this is returned:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x2b49690>
```

I have no other ideas on how to make my program click the button.

Answer (score 0):

I think **you didn't add the code for clicking on the element**. Please do that and check:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id("btnSearchAll")
element.click()
```

I did try the same code as above with JAVA, and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        f'/html/body/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/span[1]/span/span/input').click()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Please try to give proper explanation of the answer.

Comment: Sorry, the button won’t click because the full xpath get changed every time the page is refreshed, so after comparing i found the div index is changing, so i decide to use a loop with range ( div[{i}] ) to try found the correct div index then click to the element